# Display multiple email accounts in screensaver

Tags: macos, email, screensaver

a number of use our 'family' OSX Lion Mac Mini in the kitchen.  We track multiple gmail accounts by each of using a different browser.

But, none of us can tell at a glance if we have any pending emails - not without switching browser panes.

What would be ideal would be for a screensaver to show pending emails across multiple email accounts.

Can anybody offer a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to

1. Create an additional gmail account collecting all mails (by setting up rules in the original accounts to auto-forward mails to the collection account)
2. Add the RSS feed of the collection account (https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom) to the RSS Screensaver in OSX